# Is there any way of making this method run more than twice

Tags: java, methods

I was asked to write a simple calculator that could run many times as long as the user inputs 'yes' when asked "would you like to perform another operation".
so I did it using a separate method that would be used in a loop in the main method, the problem is it wont run more than twice if the answer is yes

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc2 {
    // method to be called

    static String calcmethod() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner Operation = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("choose operation to perform");
        float x, y, sum, sub, mul, div;
        String g;

        g = Operation.nextLine();
        if (g.equals("addition")) {
            System.out.println("input the first number ");
            x = Operation.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("input the second number ");
            y = Operation.nextFloat();
            sum = x + y;
            System.out.print(sum + "\n");
        } else if (g.equals("subtraction")) {
            System.out.println("input the first number ");
            x = Operation.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("input the second number ");
            y = Operation.nextFloat();
            sub = x - y;
            System.out.print(sub);
        } else if (g.equals("multiplication")) {
            System.out.println("input the first number ");
            x = Operation.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("input the second number ");
            y = Operation.nextFloat();
            mul = x * y;
            System.out.print(mul);
        } else if (g.equals("division")) {
            System.out.println("input the first number ");
            x = Operation.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("input the second number ");
            y = Operation.nextFloat();
            div = x / y;
            System.out.print(div);
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid input \n");
        }
        System.out.println("would you like to peform another operation \n");
        Scanner Flow = new Scanner(System.in);
        String w;
        w = Flow.nextLine();
        return w;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String z = calcmethod();
        if (z.equals("yes")) {
            calcmethod();
        } else {
            System.out.println("end of program");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "that would be used in a loop in the main method" <- There is no loop in your main method. A If-Else statement is **not** a loop.

Comment: Use of do while loop will help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `do-while` loop as shown in below example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String z = "";
        do {
            z = calcmethod();
        } while(z.equals("yes"));

        System.out.println("end of program");
    }
```